# get number between 0 and 1 from number between 0 and n

Tags: math

How can I calculate values between 0 and 1 from values between 0 and n. E.g. I have items with "click count" and want to get "importance" (a float between 0 and 1) from that.

My attempt: `importance = 1-1/count`

gives bad results, since the values don't distribute well…

Comment: 1-1/count -> 0/count -> inf ...

Can you put some examples of your "click count" numbers?

Comment: Carlos, divide before subtract.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also not sure what you mean...

If you are looking for a linear distribution between 0 and 1, you need to know the maximum value of n. This will be transformed to 1.

```
importance = thisCount / maxCount;
```

Comment: Depending on what your counts are like, and whether this is for ordering or weighting, you might want to take a log too.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what you mean by "don't distribute well". If you want to normalize a value between 0 and n to between 0 and 1, just divide by n.

Answer (score 3):

just divide by n

Answer (score 0):

How about `count/n`?